# Mysql distinct json key values

Tags: mysql, json

I have this mysql table that has a column containing json with random keys/values.
Using below query I can get the keys/values for all id's, but as you can see; it contains duplicate packages.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `package` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb3
```

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, time, package) VALUES
    ('myhost', '2022-05-08 09:00:00', '{"acl": "2.3.1-1", "apparmor": "2.0.4-2ubuntu2", "at": "3.2.5-1ubuntu1"}'),
    ('myhost', '2022-05-09 09:00:00', '{"acl": "2.3.1-1", "apparmor": "2.0.4-2ubuntu2", "at": "3.2.5-1ubuntu1"}'),
    ('myhost', '2022-05-10 09:00:00', '{"acl": "3.4.5-6", "apparmor": "2.0.4-2ubuntu2", "at": "3.2.5-1ubuntu1"}'),
    ('host123', '2022-05-10 09:00:00', '{"httpd": "2.4.6-97-el7.centos.5", "kpartx": "0.4.9-135.el7_9", "libcap": "2.22-11.el7"}');
```

```
select id, time, package from my_table;
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id      | time                | package                                                                                  |
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| myhost  | 2022-05-08 09:00:00 | {"acl": "2.3.1-1", "apparmor": "2.0.4-2ubuntu2", "at": "3.2.5-1ubuntu1"}                 |
| myhost  | 2022-05-09 09:00:00 | {"acl": "2.3.1-1", "apparmor": "2.0.4-2ubuntu2", "at": "3.2.5-1ubuntu1"}                 |
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | {"acl": "3.4.5-6", "apparmor": "2.0.4-2ubuntu2", "at": "3.2.5-1ubuntu1"}                 |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | {"httpd": "2.4.6-97-el7.centos.5", "kpartx": "0.4.9-135.el7_9", "libcap": "2.22-11.el7"} |
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
SELECT     id,time,pkg,Json_unquote(Json_extract(package, Concat('$.', pkg))) AS version
FROM       my_table
CROSS JOIN json_table(Json_keys(package,'$'), '$[*]' columns (pkg text path '$')) j
ORDER BY   pkg;
```

```
+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+
| id      | time                | pkg      | version               |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+
| myhost  | 2022-05-08 09:00:00 | acl      | 2.3.1-1               |
| myhost  | 2022-05-09 09:00:00 | acl      | 2.3.1-1               |
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | acl      | 3.4.5-6               |
| myhost  | 2022-05-08 09:00:00 | apparmor | 2.0.4-2ubuntu2        |
| myhost  | 2022-05-09 09:00:00 | apparmor | 2.0.4-2ubuntu2        |
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | apparmor | 2.0.4-2ubuntu2        |
| myhost  | 2022-05-08 09:00:00 | at       | 3.2.5-1ubuntu1        |
| myhost  | 2022-05-09 09:00:00 | at       | 3.2.5-1ubuntu1        |
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | at       | 3.2.5-1ubuntu1        |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | httpd    | 2.4.6-97-el7.centos.5 |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | kpartx   | 0.4.9-135.el7_9       |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | libcap   | 2.22-11.el7           |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+
```

How do I adjust my query so that it filters the duplicate packages? I only want to keep 1 `pkg` + `version` row per `id`, sorted by `time`:

```
+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+
| id      | time                | pkg      | version               |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | acl      | 3.4.5-6               |
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | apparmor | 2.0.4-2ubuntu2        |
| myhost  | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | at       | 3.2.5-1ubuntu1        |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | httpd    | 2.4.6-97-el7.centos.5 |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | kpartx   | 0.4.9-135.el7_9       |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | libcap   | 2.22-11.el7           |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with a subquery to get the leatest each `id` and `pkg`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id,time,pkg,version
FROM (
 SELECT     id,time,pkg,Json_unquote(Json_extract(package, Concat('$.', pkg))) AS version,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id,pkg ORDER BY time DESC,Json_unquote(Json_extract(package, Concat('$.', pkg)))) rn
 FROM       my_table
 CROSS JOIN json_table(Json_keys(package,'$'), '$[*]' columns (pkg text path '$')) j
) t1
WHERE rn = 1;
```

| id | time | pkg | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | httpd | 2.4.6-97-el7.centos.5 |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | kpartx | 0.4.9-135.el7_9 |
| host123 | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | libcap | 2.22-11.el7 |
| myhost | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | acl | 3.4.5-6 |
| myhost | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | apparmor | 2.0.4-2ubuntu2 |
| myhost | 2022-05-10 09:00:00 | at | 3.2.5-1ubuntu1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gq9YuFKrP5veXUN3NZYway/0)